# Hirerchical Clustering

Tags: clustering

I have a time series data of weights for 5 different objects. I am attempting to do a segmentation analysis with the help of hierarchical clustering algorithm.

I took daily average weights and using 30 such values as 30 input variables for distance matrix calculation and clustering. Hence I have an input matrix with 5 rows (5 objects) and 30 weight columns for 30 days (as 30 input variables)

My doubt here is, is it a good practice to use the values measuring the same basic input (weights) as 30 different inputs, while using the clustering analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. And you can do it using different distance measures.

If you want to find clusters of objects that are generally lighter, vs objects which are generally heavier, then yeah, you can do it with a dot product distance or an euclidean distance (which I wouldn't recommend for a 30 dimensional space).

But your data is basically a time series data. So you can look at your data from a different perspective.

For instance, would you be interested in objects which gain weight and then loose weight with a similar pattern? i.e. objects with a similar pattern through time to be in the same cluster. If yes, then you can use a [Dynamic Time Warping (DTW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) distance measure to put objects with a similar pattern together.

[image: Dynamic Time Warping]

The distance measure is independent of the clustering approach you take. Depending on your data, you may want to use a hierarchical clustering or a center based clustering. And different distance measures put your data in a differently shaped space. So you may want to use one clustering approach for one distance measure, and another for a different distance measure.